# No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa, ios-provisioning, mobileprovision

I am trying to sign an app with my client's certificates. I have received the following file from the client

[image]

I tried installing the `ios_distribution` certificate and the key (.p12). Also I have installed the provisioning profile. Now when I try to sign the app with the provisioning profile, it does show up in the drop down but I get the following error:-

```
No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "7S977Lxxx" with a private key was found
```

[image]

How can I solve this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your App's bundle identifier. Is it match with Apple develper account's AppID Identifier?

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya yes. It was different at first and it showed me the error. I changed it later to the one mentioned in the certificate

Comment: For me it was all about selecting the checkbox: _Automatically manage signing_

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the certificate in your Keychain Access app? Ideally you should show it expanded.  If correctly installed, you should see the private key associated with the cert.

Comment: I selected and deselected Automatically Manage Signing and it worked.

Comment: @JohnOttenlips Where is this automatically manage signing option?

Comment: @JuneWang, it is on your target, under the general tab => signing. There is a checkbox for automatically manage signing

Comment: I've .p12 file and profile both. I don't have apple account credentials. getting the same error. I do not have developer access too. Is it mandatory?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to have the private key of the signing certificate in the keychain along with the public key. Have you created the certificate using the same Mac (keychain) ?

## Solution #1:

- Revoke the signing certificate (reset) from apple developer portal
- Create the signing certificate again on the same mac (keychain). Then you will have the private key for the signing certificate!

## Solution #2:

- Export the signing identities from the origin xCode
- Import the signing on your xCode

Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Comment: @green you can revoke the signing certificates on the apple developer portal

However I am not sure I understood what should I export and where

Comment: I had to restart XCode to fix associating my Provisioning Profile with my Signing Certificate

Comment: The second one works for me. I could use the certificat to build app on an other mac

Answer (score 76):

I had the same issue and I have gone through all these solutions given, but none of them worked for me. But then I realised my stupid mistake. I forgot to change Code signing identity to iOS Distribution from iOS Developer, under build settings tab. Please make sure you have selected 'iOS Distribution' there.

Comment: This is the answer if you're dealing with legacy apps. Also choose "apple" instead of "ios" because that's the new cross-platform style.

Comment: @CGuess 's suggestion helped with conjunction to to Hasan's answer. Setting the identity to "Apple Distribution" from "iOS Distribution" worked

Comment: I think Xcode at some point changes this for you, maybe a bug, because I would NEVER change this yet ran into the same issue.  I feel like creating a million sock puppet accounts just to upvote this.

Answer (score 26):

[image]

**Solution Steps:**

1. Unchecked "Automatically manage signing".
2. Select "Provisioning profile" in "Signing (Release)" section.
3. No signing certificate error will be show.
4. Then below the error has a "Manage Certificates" button. click the button.

[image]

5. This window will come. Click the + sign and click "iOS Distribution". xcode will create the private key for your distribution certificate and error will be gone.

Comment: Why is unchecking the Automatically manage signing necessary? Won't Xcode manage it for you automatically?

Answer (score 22):

Tried the above solutions with no luck ... restarting my mac solved the issue...

Comment: After restarting xcode didnt work, i restarted my mac, and it worked. Thanks. It wouldnt have occured to me.

Comment: Apple hardware, Apple software, Apple remote service. Sigh.

Comment: Lol, Thanks man. Even i tried other methods and this one worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had to reauthenticate in the Mac Systems Settings as well as in XCode.

For XCode 15, click on Xcode -> Settings... -> Accounts -> sign in again

Answer (score 3):

I literally just went to "Signing & Capabilities" for my build target and *took no further action* and the next build worked.

Merely visiting that screen seemed to update the Signing Certificate

Answer (score 3):

Apple updated their agreement, so I had to

- go to apple connect
- accept the agreement
- toggle automatic manage signing off and on

Answer (score 2):

The problem for us was the expiry of our Apple Developer Program membership

Answer (score 1):

Goto **Xcode -> Prefrences** and import the profile [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I try the Import Developer Accounts options, it shows the certificates in my folder, but they are all grayed out

Comment: This helped me. In my case, I just had to log in again on the Xcode > Preferences > Accounts tab and then click the button to refresh my cert.

Comment: @MrColes where is the button for refresh?

Answer (score 1):

I got the "No signing certificate" error when running Xcode 11.3 on macOS 10.14.x Mojave.  (but after Xcode 12 was released.)

I was also using Fastlane.  My fix was to set `generate_apple_certs` to `false` when running Match. This seemed to generate signing certificates that were backwards-compatible with Xcode 11.3

Match documentation - https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/

This is the relevant section of my Fastfile:

```
platform :ios do
  lane :certs do
    force = false
    match(type: "development", generate_apple_certs: false, force: force, app_identifier: "your.app.identifier.dev")
    match(type: "adhoc",       generate_apple_certs: false, force: force, app_identifier: "your.app.identifier.beta")
    match(type: "appstore",    generate_apple_certs: false, force: force, app_identifier: "your.app.identifier")
  end

  ...
```

Comment: I'm 11.3 and still having the issue I had one app that worked  a couple of days but now another app doesn't work I tried everything suggested here and so far nothing...I even deleted all certificates from keychain and redid still no cigar... I always have this issue when changing to a different machine

Answer (score 0):

Double click and install the production certificate in your key chain. This might resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am working for an enterprise company so we archive the app on more than mac. The issue is related to computers count. You should archive the app a mac which was created certified on keychain.

Identifier and Profiles are the same but don't forget that you create a certificate for each mac machine.

So, We need to have as many certificates as there are computers. The below link is useful for creating a certificate.

https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-code-sign-publish-ios-apps/

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure to have the cert. included in your provisioning profile but still getting this issue then give below steps one try.

- Turn off you mac's internet access.
- Tick Automatic manage signing.
- Untick automatic manage signing.
- Turn on you mac's internet access.

Error should go away.

**Explaination for steps:**

Sometimes xcode couldn't sync settings automatically. Above steps update it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Double click and install the production certificate in your key chain.

This might resolve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were logged out or a failure with the signing cert process happened on the OSX. In my case - a restart solved it. You can uncheck the Automatic manage signing, and check it again (after restart) and it will work

Answer (score -4):

Our solution was to run

`fastlane match`

as I forgot we setup a Matchfile.

Comment: @babibo Not exactly. `fastlane` and `match` are open source projects. Its a defined command and not custom. It could help someone who uses `fastlane` and `match` and did not understand that they needed to run that command... No need for the negative-ness mate