# How do I replace/update an existing certificate in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

In my `Xcode` project I have a `certificate` that has expired. I got a new one from the associated web page, and it's now on my desktop. So, my question is, how do I replace the old `certificate` with the new one I just downloaded? I have checked a few threads with similar questions like this,

[How to install a certificate in Xcode (preparing for app store submission)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156128/how-to-install-a-certificate-in-xcode-preparing-for-app-store-submission)

But it doesn't seem to adress the issue as the answers are old and likely outdated.

My first though is to delete the existing one and just drag and drop a new one in its place, but that didn't work, so I guess there must be a more sophisticated way.

****EDIT***
If I locate the old `certificate` in the project and just replace it with the new one, will that work?

Comment: You just need to double click on the certificate to add it into the keychain and you will able to select it. if you look at the signing in the target settings.
In some projects you need to change it in the build settings.

Comment: Do you mean add it under Target < Signing & Capabilities < Signing < Provision profile? Or where? I can't select it under provision profiles... Do you think you could elaborate a bit? :)

Comment: @screenMonkeyMonkeyMan Just do double click on your profile. It will automatically added/updated in your keychain. Same will be reflected in your xcode project if you renewed the old profile else you need to select the new profile in xcode as it will be appeared on the drop-down on profile eligible list..

Comment: If you go through the answers on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/45050902/5089923 . you will get an idea, just go through the answers.